# Laravel CRUD destroy method not working. Cannot pass data from the view to the controller in order to delete the data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, crud

**Destroy method not working**

I am trying to delete an image from my database but I am receiving the following error:

> Undefined variable: portfolio (View: C:\MyProjects\bubblehouseProject\resources\views\admin\portfolio\addPortfolio.blade.php)

I believe there is something wrong with the logic I am trying to implement in my Laravel application. I am using Eloquent ORM.

**Controller:**

```
    public function Destroy($id) {


     $portfolio = new Portfolio();

     $portfolio::find($id);

     $portfolio->delete();

     return redirect('addPortfolio')->with('delete', 'The image has been successfully deleted!');

}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('addPortfolio/{id}', 'AddPortfolioController@Destroy');
```

**View:**

```
<form action="{{ route('addPortfolioController.Destroy', $portfolio->id) }}">
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
       <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
       {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```

I am not entirely sure that this is the right way to delete data from the database.

Comment: You are not passing `$portfolio` to your view -- which you can't do anyway really without serialization and flashing to session since you are doing a redirect. Why are you not just doing something like `return view('addPortfolio', ['portfolio' => $portfolio]);`?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am doing something similar in my ` public function Index () { $var ['portfolio'] = Portfolio::find('id'); } `and then I pass the data to the view like that ` return view('addPortfolio', $var); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Route**

```
Route::delete('addPortfolio/{id}', 'AddPortfolioController@Destroy')->name('portfolio.destroy');
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('portfolio.destroy', $portfolio->id) }}">
   {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">       
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  if(Portfolio::destroy($id)) {
    return redirect('addPortfolio')->with('success', 'The image has been successfully deleted!');
  } else {
    return redirect('addPortfolio')->with('error', 'Please try again!');
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a bad thing to downvote without comment the reason

Comment: Hi mate, I am not entirely sure why this was downvoted. Actually, your reply was really helpful so thank you for the help!

Comment: Your welcome. somebodies make weird things but it doesn't matter while it's helpful to you.